# How to update range for test in loop that is changing range

Tags: excel, loops, range

I want my loop to test for cell that is looking for a value. Problem is my range is changing because the loop is adding rows. How can I update my set range?

`WorkRng1` and `WorkRng2` are public variables set with an input box

Here is my code so far:

```
Dim foundRange As Range
Dim manualRng As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
matchCounter = 0
On Error Resume Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each Rng2 In WorkRng2
        If Rng2.Interior.Color = VBA.RGB(255, 0, 0) And Rng2.Value > 0 Then
                blkRow.Copy
            LastRow = Range(WorkRng1.Column & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'tests for last filled row in range 1
            Set foundRange = WorkRng1.Find(Rng2.Offset(-1, 0).Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
            If foundRange Is Nothing Then
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
                MsgBox "Cannot find where to put " & Rng2, vbInformation, "OOPS!"
                Set manualRng = Application.InputBox("Please select the cell where you would like to add " & Rng2, "LOCATION PLEASE", Type:=8)
                manualRng.Select
                Selection.EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
                Else
            WorkRng1.Find(Rng2.Offset(-1, 0).Value, LookIn:=xlValues).Select
                ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
                Selection.EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
            End If
```

I was thinking I would add a `lastRow` test to it but I'm stuck on the syntax for the range. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Loop backwards using a counter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested I solved this by setting the found range as the entire column. Here is my working code:

```
Dim matchCounter As Integer
Dim foundRange As Range
Dim manualRng As Range
Dim lastRow As Long
matchCounter = 0
On Error Resume Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each Rng2 In WorkRng2
        If Rng2.Interior.Color = VBA.RGB(255, 0, 0) And Rng2.Value > 0 Then
                blkRow.Copy
            lastRow = WorkRng1.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row 'tests for last filled row in range 1
            Set foundRange = Range(Cells(1, WorkRng1.Column), Cells(lastRow, WorkRng1.Column)).Find(Rng2.Offset(-1, 0).Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
            If foundRange Is Nothing Then
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
                MsgBox "Cannot find where to put " & Rng2, vbInformation, "OOPS!"
                Set manualRng = Application.InputBox("Please select the cell where you would like to add " & Rng2, "LOCATION PLEASE", Type:=8)
                blkRow.Copy
                manualRng.Select
                Selection.EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
                Else
            WorkRng1.Find(Rng2.Offset(-1, 0).Value, LookIn:=xlValues).Select
                ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
                Selection.EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
            End If
```